# Dask with Tensorflow - Joblib?

Tags: tensorflow, dask, joblib

I was amazed at the results of DASK and JOBLIB when testing our different algorithms in a multi-node dash cluster with SciKit Learn and XGBoost.
I would like to know how to combine tensorflow 2.0 with Dask and Joblib to accomplish parallel computing with neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are currently any "out of the box" solutions for this, though I believe there is chatter about building this functionality into `dask` or `dask-ml`. In early development too, but check out `ray`, they have some info in their docs about distributed TensorFlow: https://docs.ray.io/en/master/raysgd/raysgd_tensorflow.html